# Catalog product image upload files button not responding

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I tested it in all Magento version shops we have version like 1.7, 1.8 and 1.9 and in all the button `Upload files` is not responding when I click on it. I tried to open the shops in Chrome, Mozilla and IE. With what could be this connected ?

I update the Adobe Flash on my computer but it is still not working.

In console there is no error.

How could I resolve this ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to upload images to catalog products you need to click on **Browse Files** button first, then select files you want to upload and after that click on **Upload Files** button to Upload images to the product.